# Unable to Display Google Map in Liferay 7 MVC Portlet

Tags: javascript, jsp, liferay, portlet, liferay-7

Here is my view.jsp, it is just the example from Google. I wanted to just get this to display before moving forward with it:

```
<%@ include file="/init.jsp" %>

    <p>
        <b><liferay-ui:message key="mapsportlet_mapsPortletmvcportlet.caption"/></b>
    </p>

<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 20%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 20%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDeekwNluL4ssJ3QAFGPSkFHYYQvZoNbVM&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm running a local instance of liferay 7 on localhost:8080. I believe the JavaScript is firing because I did not have my API key set correctly and I could see in the javascript console that it was being denied. After fixing my API key, I no longer see any errors in the console of the browser, but I don't see the map display in my Portlet.

Do you see anything wrong with the view.jsp? Or is there another way I should be going about this?

Comment: On inspection of page DOM,what does the "map" div show as content,or it blank??

Comment: I recommend to read Olafs anwer below and revise your markup and accept Olafs anwer to give him credit. All your tags are most likely not relevant to your question. You are simply not aware of the basic concepts of portlet architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You're tagging this question with "liferay", so I'm assuming that you're using the JSP you post as a portlet's view. A portlet must never contain `<html>`, `<head>` or `<body>` because this markup will be added by the portal.

Also be careful with the `map` id: If you add the same portlet to the page twice, this won't work as well as you'll end up with a duplicate HTML element id. If this ends up being a problem, utilize `<portlet:namespace/>` to make the identifier unique. You might also want to try if some other portlet adds this id already. It might be working already, just being invisible - depending on where this id has currently been used already.

Also, I'm not sure if the `<style>` will or will not be ignored when contained in a superfluous `<html><head>` section. Try by explicitly styling your `<div>` with an appropriate height.